# Clear navigationController stack when push ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, stack

I have a navigation controller that push some viewcontroller. It works fine, but I can't clear navigation controller stack and so i've got memory warning...

Here is what I want to do :

```
Viewcontroller 1 : HomeViewController
ViewController 2 : LandingPageViewController
ViewController 3 : DetailsInnovViewController

homeViewController -> Push -> landingPageViewController -> Push -> detailsPageViewController -> Push -> homeViewController
```

It works but I want a new homeViewController, not the old. Si it can be deleted from navigation controller.

Here is how I push homeViewController from detailsPageViewController with my navigationController :

```
- (void)pushHomeVC
{
    [LoginModel incrementCountedInnov];

    for (UIViewController* vc in self.viewControllers) {
        if ([vc isKindOfClass:[DetailsInnovViewController class]]) {
            DetailsInnovViewController* dpvc = (DetailsInnovViewController*)vc;
            [dpvc bannerHide];
            break;
        }
    }

    for (UIViewController* vc in self.viewControllers) {
        if ([vc isKindOfClass:[HomeViewController class]]) {
            [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            [self pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thx for helping!

Comment: Unfortunately HomeViewController is not set as root...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I have recently had a similar problem and found that this solution worked for me:

```
[navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[navigationController setViewControllers:@[navigationController.topViewController]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found how to do this :

```
- (void)pushHomeVC
{
    [LoginModel incrementCountedInnov];

    for (UIViewController* vc in self.viewControllers) {
        if ([vc isKindOfClass:[DetailsInnovViewController class]]) {
            DetailsInnovViewController* dpvc = (DetailsInnovViewController*)vc;
            [dpvc bannerHide];
            break;
        }
    }

    HomeViewController* homeVC = (HomeViewController*)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home-vc"];
    [self pushViewController:homeVC animated:YES];
}
```

And my pushViewController method :

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (isTransitioning == YES) {
            [futureViewControllers addObject:viewController];
        } else {
            isTransitioning = YES;
            if (self.viewControllers.count > 6) {
                [super popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            }
            [super pushViewController:viewController animated:(BOOL)animated];
        }
    }
}
```

Thx !